# cPanel with Tomcat 7 installation successful but not showing /usr/local/jakarta folder under root

Tags: java, tomcat7, cpanel, whm, website-hosting

I have successfully installed Tomcat 7 using cPanel on IWEB server. I got the installation successful message too. I am able to hit the tomcat home page using www.domain.com:8080 and it directs me to Tomcat's home page. You may take a look at http://67.205.89.174:8080/

The main challenge is, in order to access Manager App, I need admin credentials, which should ideally be found in /root/usr/local/jakarta/..../tomcat-users.xml

When I connect to 67.205.89.174 using WinSCP, I don't see any "jakarta" folder located there.

This is my first time I am trying to host a website and everything is new to me. I am doing my self study by going through some online documentations, blogs, videos etc.. related to cPanel-Tomcat 7 installation.

I would appreciate any help by guru's online here so that it can drastically save my time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat 7 configuration directory is /usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/conf and you can check your user configuration in /usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml file.

Comment: Thank you!! It helped me. I did execute "<b>find</b>" command from unix shell to locate tomcat-users.xml file if at all located under /<root>/.. and found that as well. But Thanks again for confirming this, I appreciate the help

Comment: I have one more question
I have uploaded and deployed my web application in "public_html" folder. But I am able to access it only via following link ex: www.domain.com/MyWebApp... Rather, www.domain.com should serve as good as hitting www.domain.com/MyWebApp

In order to achieve this, I have modified server.xml appropriately and I am able to access MyWebApp when I hit www.domain.com

The only problem is, with this method, I see images are not displayed properly. The Web Application is perfectly fine and works well when I access via www.domain.com/MyWebApp

Any idea, what I might be missing?